# VS2015 Setup project error 80040154 Class not registered

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, 64-bit, setup-project

My company is developing an application which makes use of the BOSCH Video SDK. I've included the required DLL files in my Setup project, and I believe they're being registered when my project is installed, but I am getting the "Class not registered" error at runtime..

I suspect my issues are coming from the fact that this application is being compiled in x64 and is using the 64-bit DLL's from the BOSCH Video SDK. This is intentional and we definitely want this to install and run in 64 bit mode.

The exact error message is "Retreiving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {D12FF18F-AFC2-4E6E-9FEB-8FC4B57FFC93} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))".

[image]

In my setup project all of the dependencies are marked as Register: vsdraCOM.

[image]

Both my setup project and the application project itself have their target set as 'x64'.

[image]

[image]

In my Setup project I have also implemented the solution found [here](http://www.codingnotebook.com/2012/01/systembadimageformatexception-on-x64.html) which details using the Fix64bitInstallUtilLib.js script and the 64-bit InstallUtilLib.dll to properly install a 64-bit project without running into the BadImageFormatException problem. My project installs and launches without any issues but when it hits the first line which uses the BOSCH Video SDK I get the "Class not registered" error.

I have also tried to manually register the DLL files using both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of regsvr32.exe but each time I get an error reading "entry-point DllRegisterServer" was not found.

[image]

I'm not sure what else there is left to try. I feel like there is a critical piece to this puzzle that I am missing. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Our end-goal here is to be able to deploy our setup.msi file to a fresh client machine without having to first manually install the BOSCH Video SDK. I thought this would be as easy as including the required DLL files and setting Register: vsdraCOM but I guess it isn't that simple.

Comment: It looks like that class is the DeviceConnector class from the Video SDK, and therefore not part of your code or registration. I suspect you need to install whatever runtime that SDK supplies to support its use. It's unlikely that you need to distribute all those Dlls and supporting files in your setup.

Comment: Funny you should mention that. I'm only now discovering the help file bundled with the SDK (go figure) and it does have a section on the Video SDK Redistributable Package. I'm going to toy around with it and report back with my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer was to include the Bosch Video SDK Runtime with my installer, create an app manifest in my project, and add the SDK as a depdency to the manifest. It was also convenient to add a PropertyGroup to the CSPROJ file with the condition 'Release|x64' so that the manifest is only included when compiled in Release mode.

1. Add the Bosch Video SDK Runtime folder to source control.
   [image]
2. Add runtime files and folders to Application Folder in setup project.[image]
3. Add app.manifest file to project and add dependency section for the SDK.
   [image]
4. Use a text editor to edit your CSPROJ file and add a PropertyGroup with a condition for 'Release|x64' so that your manifest is only used on release versions.
   [image]

Hopefully this proves useful for someone at some point. The real lesson here is to actually read the Help files from time to time..

Comment: I got the issue because the samples downloaded from bosch have references to the x84 dlls in the bin folder, but I'd installed the x64 sdk. Removing and adding the correct references fixed it but this helped me work it out.

Comment: No problem bud. I figure I burn a bunch of time trying to figure something out what is a few more minutes to post the answer I found. Peace.